# How to partially Match cell against another partial cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a problem with two tables which I need to compare dates for the same reference. The problem is that

1. the dates are different formats and
2. superfluous data is also contained within both date cells.

Global

```
No. Date
1   1992-08-25 00:00:00.000
2   2015-05-19 00:00:00.000
3   2000-01-12 00:00:00.000
```

Local

```
No. Date
1   25.08.1992 00:00:00.000000000 GMT
1   28.08.1992 00:00:00.000000000 GMT
2   19.05.2015 00:00:00.000000000 GMT
3   12.01.2000 00:00:00.000000000 GMT
3   17.01.2000 00:00:00.000000000 GMT
```

Note that the date formats between the two tables differ and contain lots of time and zero data that is not needed. So ideally I would like to see the format as `DD-MM-YYYY`.

I would like to return only the Global and Local entries where the Local date differs from Global date. So from the data above, I would want to see:

```
No. Date        No. Date
1   25-08-1992  1   28-08-1992
3   12-01-2000  3   17-01-2000
```

I would put my attempts so far, but to be honest I have no idea on how to tackle the partial cell matching and re-formatting.

Any ideas?

Update:
I tried a solution from @Sarslan and substituted my table and field names which resulted in this:

```
WITH G AS 
(
    SELECT [UPC], CONVERT(DATE,LEFT([GLOBAL RELEASE DATE], CHARINDEX(' ', 
[GLOBAL RELEASE DATE])),120)  [Date] FROM [dsched_migration].[emi].
[EMI_Global]
) 
,L AS 
(
    SELECT [UPC], CONVERT(DATE,LEFT([TERR_REL_DATE], CHARINDEX(' ', 
[TERR_REL_DATE])),104)  [Date] FROM [dsched_migration].[emi].
[terr_release_dates]
) 
SELECT 
    G.UPC, CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.Date,105) [GLOBAL RELEASE DATE],
    L.UPC, CONVERT(VARCHAR,L.Date,105) [TERR_REL_DATE]   
FROM 
    G INNER JOIN L ON L.UPC = G.UPC
WHERE L.Date <> G.Date
```

I keep getting this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: why are these stored as strings in the first place? Using an actual date/time column type would remove problems like this

Comment: Unfortunately this was how the data was received from my vendor. I have no control as to how I receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies but found a solution:

Created a new column then ran this query to confirm the conversion:

```
SELECT  '19.10.2009 00:00:00.000000000 GMT',
        CONVERT(datetime, LEFT('19.10.2009 00:00:00.000000000 GMT',10), 104)
```

This gave me the right format then I ran the following query to update the new column with the formatted date:

```
update LocalDate
      set REL_DATE = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(TERR_REL_DATE,10), 104)
```

Luckily my Global date was already in datetime so I then simply joined the two tables and ran my comparison against the new updated time

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select a.no, to_char(a.date,'DD-mm-YYY') Date1 , b.no, to_char(b.date,'DD-mm-YYY') Date2
from Global a inner join Local b on (a.no=b.no)
)
where Date1<>Date2;
```

Comment: Hi substituted your formula to my table and have this: select * from
(
select glo.upc, to_char(glo.global_release_date,'DD-mm-YYY') Date1 , loc.upc, to_char(loc.terr_rel_date,'DD-mm-YYY') Date2
from emi.emi_global glo inner join emi.terr_release_dates loc on (glo.upc=loc.upc)
)
where Date1<>Date2; I keep getting an error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: FYI I'm using MS SQL Server. The 'to_char' seems to be springing the error

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
;WITH G AS 
(
    SELECT [No], CONVERT(DATE,LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX(' ', [Date])),120)  [Date] FROM [GLobal]
) 
,L AS 
(
    SELECT [No], CONVERT(DATE,LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX(' ', [Date])),104)  [Date] FROM [Local]
) 
SELECT 
    G.No, CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.Date,105) [Date],
    L.No, CONVERT(VARCHAR,L.Date,105) [Date]    
FROM 
    G INNER JOIN L ON L.No = G.No
WHERE L.Date <> G.Date
```

Result

```
No          Date                           No          Date
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
1           25-08-1992                     1           28-08-1992
3           12-01-2000                     3           17-01-2000
```

Comment: Hi @sarslan, I tried substituting my table and field names and the code is in my post but I keep getting the following error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Any ideas?

Comment: When you run this script `SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,LEFT('1992-08-25 00:00:00.000', CHARINDEX(' ', '1992-08-25 00:00:00.000')),120) , CONVERT(DATE,LEFT('25.08.1992 00:00:00.000000000 GMT', CHARINDEX(' ', '25.08.1992 00:00:00.000000000 GMT')),104)` are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

When you have some formatted string that format will never change you can simplify it like this - this will also give you more flexibility -:

```
;with tg as (
    select [No], 
        -- Format is : yyyy-mm-dd
        left([Date], 4) yyyy, substring([Date], 6, 2) mm, substring([Date], 9, 2) dd
    from g
), tl as (
    select [No], 
        -- Format is: dd-mm-yyyy
        substring([Date], 7, 4) yyyy, substring([Date], 4, 2) mm, left([Date], 2) dd
    from l
)
select *
from tg
inner join tl
  on tg.[No] = tl.[No]
 and not (tg.yyyy = tl.yyyy and tg.mm = tl.mm and tg.dd = tl.dd);
```